# Is lignification within plants a reversible process? If so which factors can reverse lignification?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, botany

[Lignification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin) is an important process in plants such as trees to allow for structural rigidity. Is this process reversible by the plant and if so which factors influence this reversibility?

Comment: A quick search found [Ursache, 2021](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33686223/) that says in the abstract lignification is "thought to be irreversible", but I haven't chased it down.

Comment: Do you mean specifically delignification that occurs in vivo by means of metabolic processes in the same plant that performed lignification? Delignification is a well-known process of microbial decomposers e.g. white rot (https://bnrc.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s42269-019-0094-x), and which could presumably occur in living tissues infected by some pathogen, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: I edited your post to make it more concise — please re-edit if you think I've altered your meaning, but try keep your posts as clean and clear as possible. To thank someone for a helpful/useful comment just upvote it (as I did). It would also be helpful if you added in more background — i.e. tell us where you've looked for answers, more about what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Also, can we assume that by "factors" you mean enzymes or are you more interested in things like environmental conditions?

Comment: I'm interested in any factors that's why I let it unspecified. A quick google scholar search did not return any results if plants are capable of reversing lignification. As I'm pretty limited time-wise I offered a bounty..